# C#. Можно ли используя NLog передать в него значение переменной из кода C#

Tags: c#, nlog

Имеется некий Updater на C# с используемой библиотекой [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).
Updater получает пакеты для обновлений из папок содержащие в своем имени номер версии, например название папки `3.0.14`

Допустим в Updater'e была выбрана версия `3.0.14`, он будет в дальнейшем работать только с этой папкой и брать оттуда пакеты для обновления окружения.

Вопрос: как заставить NLog писать лог в папку с выбранной версией для обновления, в моем примере хотелось бы писать лог в директорию `.../3.0.14/Logs/log-file.txt`

Можно ли это сделать с NLog?

Сейчас NLog настроен следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd" autoReload="true" throwExceptions="false" internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >
  <targets>
    <target name="log"
            xsi:type="File"
            layout="${longdate} [${level}]: ${message}"
            deleteOldFileOnStartup="false"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            keepFileOpen ="true"
            fileName="${basedir}\Logs\log-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
            encoding="UTF-8"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="log"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

В коде:

```
private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Comment: Задавайте путь к логам программно. Абсолютно все настройки можно задать кодом, а не конфигом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно настроить NLOG кодом, чтобы он писал строго куда задано и никто не мог переназначить это дело:

```
  var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
  var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
  config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);
  fileTarget.FileName = @"${basedir}/${processname}_${date:format=yyyy_MM_dd}.log";
  fileTarget.Layout = @"${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} ${processid} ${threadid} ${logger} ${message}";
  var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
  config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);
  LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо